# conditionally load module with require (base on node env)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am using webpack to create bundle.
I want to load either b.js or c.js depending on node variable.

```
export default (process.env.FOO) ?
require('./b').default : require('./c').default;
```

It works fine when process.env.FOO is defined (that is FALSE or TRUE is assigned). 
But when process.env.FOO is not defined it seems that webpack bundle both files.

Comment: I think that's because webpack does the bundling before even looking at the conditions. This is probably why there are weird things like https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader

Comment: If I use process.env.NODE_ENV instead of any other variable (like process.env.FOO above) it works fine.